Cancelling out piecewise functions
I am currently trying to rearrange this
$$\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(x-z\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}~|~x,y>0$$,
into this
$$\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}$$, where$(z-x)^+=\max (z-x,0)$,
utilizing the property $$ x = x^+ + (-x)^+$$
From what I can tell, $\int^y_0 (z-x)^+dz=\int^y_0 (z-x)dz+\int^y_0 (x-z)^+dz$,
but how can I convert $\int^y_0 (x-z)dz$ to $\int^y_0 (x-z)^+dz$ without cancelling out $\int^y_0 (z-x)^+dz$?
Any help would be appreciated!

There is some mistake. The two terms cancel each other: $$zg''-xg''+xg''-zg''=0$$

The full question is actually to prove $$ g\left(x\right)-g\left(y\right)=\ g^\prime\left(y\right)\left(x-y\right)+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz+\ \int_{y}^{\infty}{\left(x-z\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}}$$ using integration by parts, and I'm at $ g^\prime\left(y\right)\left(x-y\right)+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}+\left(\int_{y}^{x}{\left(x-z\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(x-z\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}\right)$  assuming g'(0) is 0, and stuck on the original problem.

The full question is now asked (and answered) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4966035/42969.
