Integration by parts for twice differentiable functions
I am stuck a question where I have to convert the LHS to RHS:
$$g\left(x\right)-g\left(y\right)=\ g^\prime\left(y\right)\left(x-y\right)+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz+\ \int_{y}^{\infty}{\left(x-z\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}} ,\forall x,y>0$$
I substitute $u = g'(z)$ and $dv = 1dz$, I can rewrite $g\left(x\right)-g\left(y\right)$ as $\int^x_y g'(z)dz=xg'(x)-yg'(y)-\int_{y}^{x}{zg^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz\ }$
I expanded the integral term$$-\int^x_y zg''(z)dz = \int^y_0zg''(z)dz -\int^x_0zg''(z)dz = \int^y_0(z-x+x)g''(z)dz-\int^x_0(z-x+x)g''(z)dz\\=\int^y_0(z-x)g''(z)dz+\int^x_0(x-z)g''(z)dz+x\int^y_0 g''(z)dz-x\int^x_0 g''(z)dz$$
Assuming g'(0) = 0, it can be rewritten as
$$ \int^y_0(z-x)g''(z)dz+\int^x_0(x-z)g''(z)dz+xg'(y)-xg'(x)$$
and substituting back to the original formula I got:
$$ g(x)-g(y) =g'(y)(x-y)+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}+\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-z\right)g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}$$
I then split $$\int^x_0 (x-z)g''(x)dz = \int^x_y (x-z)g''(x)dz + \int^y_0 (x-z)g''(x)dz$$,
since $((x-z)^+ =0\forall z>x,\int^x_y (x-z)g''(z)dz=\int^\infty_y (x-z)^+g''(z)dz$
but then I have no clue how to turn $$\int^y_0 (z-x)dz +\int^y_0(x-z)dz$$to $$\int^y_0 (z-x)^+dz$$ to get the RHS $$\ g^\prime\left(y\right)\left(x-y\right)+\int_{0}^{y}{\left(z-x\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz+\ \int_{y}^{\infty}{\left(x-z\right)^+g^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)dz}}$$.
Any thoughts?

Not really on topic: double dollar signs ends the display math expression, so you want the punctuation before that happens.  With a single dollar sign, having the punctuation after makes sense because the punctuation comes after the text item.

Integration by parts with $u(z) = g'(z) $ and $v(z) = z-x$ gives
$$
 g(x) -g(y) = \int_y^x 1 \cdot g'(z) \, dz = (x-y)g'(y) + \int_y^x(x-y)g''(z) \, dz \ ,
$$
so it remains to show that
$$ \tag{$*$}
\int_y^x (x-z)g''(z)\, dz  = \int_0^y (z-x)^+ g''(z)\, dz + \int_y^\infty (x-z)^+ g''(z)\, dz \, .
$$
If $x \le y$ then
$$
\int_0^y (z-x)^+ g''(z)\, dz = \int_x^y (z-x) g''(z)\, dz = \int_y^x (x-z)g''(z)\, dz
$$
since $(z-x)^+ = 0$ for $0 \le z < x$, and
$$
 \int_y^\infty (x-z)^+ g''(z)\, dz = 0
$$
since $x-z \le x-y \le 0$ in the second integral.
Similarly, if $x > y$ then
$$
\int_0^y (z-x)^+ g''(z)\, dz  = 0
$$
and
$$
\int_y^\infty (x-z)^+ g''(z)\, dz = \int_y^x (x-z)g''(z)\, dz \, ,
$$
so $(*)$ holds in both cases.
Remark: If $g$ is defined and twice continuously differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$ then $(*)$ can be written in a more symmetric form
$$ 
\int_y^x (x-z)g''(z)\, dz  = \int_{-\infty}^y (z-x)^+ g''(z)\, dz + \int_y^\infty (x-z)^+ g''(z)\, dz \, .
$$
and holds not only for positive arguments but for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$.
